# How to access arrays from other class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I need help in accessing an array from a different class so I can change the values in a different class.

```
public class A320TicketOrderFlorida extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static boolean A320FloridaBusinessA[]=new boolean [6];
    static boolean A320FloridaBusinessC[]=new boolean [6];
    static boolean A320FloridaBusinessD[]=new boolean [6];
    static boolean A320FloridaBusinessF[]=new boolean [6];
    static boolean A320FloridaCoachA[]=new boolean [32];
    static boolean A320FloridaCoachB[]=new boolean [32];
    static boolean A320FloridaCoachC[]=new boolean [32];
    static boolean A320FloridaCoachD[]=new boolean [32];
    static boolean A320FloridaCoachE[]=new boolean [32];
    static boolean A320FloridaCoachF[]=new boolean [32];
```

How can I access the arrays in this class to a TicketRefund.java class to change the values of the array?

Comment: add an access modifier to your class properties. See [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and access them like A320TicketOrderFlorida.A320FloridaBusinessA inside your TicketRefund class

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make the arrays public, such as

```
public static boolean A320FloridaBusinessA[] = new boolean[6];
```

Then you could access it by writing `A320TicketOrderFlorida.A320FloridaBusinessA`

However, in general it is a bad practise to have shared mutable static variable, so perhaps you should think about migrating these static fields to non-static fields. Then you would have to pass a `A320TicketOrderFlorida` instance to `TicketRefund`. Moreover it may be worth considering refactoring these arrays to a shared object which would be shared between `A320TicketOrderFlorida` and `TicketRefund`.